# Recurring billing using the ActiveMerchant Gem through Authorize.net stopped working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authorize.net, activemerchant

We have some legacy code that's been running just fine for years, but recently we've been getting this error when trying to do recurring billing:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `recurring' for #<ActiveMerchant::Billing::AuthorizeNetGateway:0xf52dda34>):
```

Processing a regular one-time transaction still works perfectly fine, the code is a simple:

```
ActiveMerchant::Billing::Base.gateway('authorize_net').new(:login => xxx, :password => xxx, :test => xxx)

gateway.recurring( ...)
```

Comment: Just a simple question: any update of gems recently or any changes on the production server?

Comment: Recurring functionality is deprecated. You are probably running newer version of ActiveMerchant, than you want to. try `puts ActiveMerchant::VERSION`